# How to dynamically determine optimal chunk size and thread count for asynchronous file uploads?

Tags: python, upload, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am working on a Python application that uploads files to a web system asynchronously. The application uses a configuration file where we can specify the chunk size and the number of threads for the upload process. Uploading a file involves three steps: initiating the upload, uploading multiple chunks, and completing the upload.

My challenge lies in adapting to varying internet speeds across different installations. I'm seeking a way to automatically determine the most efficient chunk sizes and thread counts, rather than setting these parameters manually.

Also it's cost-effective to use larger chunks, as each PUT operation to S3 storage incurs a cost.

Can anyone suggest strategies or algorithms to dynamically adjust chunk sizes and thread counts based on network conditions? Any insights or references to similar implementations would be greatly appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Uploading process management.

Created on Mon Dec  4 19:58:33 2023
@author: Ivan Gusev
"""


import os
import time
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from tools.logger import logger
from config_manager import ConfigManager
from tools.custom_errors import ChunkUploadError

config = ConfigManager() # Singleton


class FileUploadManager:
    def __init__(self, session_manager, auth_manager, manager_queue):
        self.session_manager = session_manager
        self.auth_manager = auth_manager
        self.manager_queue = manager_queue

    async def upload_file(self, file_path, upload_id, uploaded_parts=[], chunk_size=None):
        if not await self._wait_for_file_stability(file_path):
            return False
        
        logger.debug(f'Uploaded parts: {", ".join(map(str, uploaded_parts))}')

        session = await self.session_manager.get_session()
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
            success = await self._upload_chunks(session, file, upload_id,
                                      uploaded_parts, chunk_size, file_path)

        return success

    async def _wait_for_file_stability(self, file_path, sleep_time=2):
        if not os.path.exists(file_path):
            logger.info(f'File {file_path} not found.')
            return False

        last_size, current_size = -1, 0
        while current_size != last_size:
            last_size = current_size
            current_size = os.path.getsize(file_path)
            await asyncio.sleep(sleep_time)

        return True

    async def _upload_chunks(self, session, file, upload_id,
                             uploaded_parts, chunk_size, file_path):
        logger.info(f"The file size is {self.count_chunks(file)} chunks.")
        max_concurrent_uploads = config.max_workers
        semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(max_concurrent_uploads)
        part_number = 1
        tasks = []
        if chunk_size:
            size = chunk_size
        else:
            size = config.chunk_size
        while chunk := file.read(size):
            if part_number not in uploaded_parts:
                logger.debug(f"Chunk #{part_number} has been added to the upload queue.")
                task = asyncio.create_task(
                    self._upload_chunk_with_semaphore(semaphore, session, chunk, part_number, upload_id, file_path))
                tasks.append(task)
            part_number += 1

        results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        success = True
        for success, part_number in results:
            if success:
                pass
            else:
                logger.error(f"Chunk #{part_number} uploading error.")
                success = False
        return success

    async def _upload_chunk_with_semaphore(self, semaphore, session, chunk, part_number, upload_id, file_path):
        async with semaphore:
            return await self._upload_chunk(session, chunk, part_number, upload_id, file_path)

    async def _upload_chunk(self, session, chunk, part_number, upload_id, file_path):
        logger.info(f"Chunk #{part_number} is uploading.")
        upload_chunk_url = config.url + '/api/media/uploadChunk'
        
        data = aiohttp.FormData()
        data.add_field('partNumber', str(part_number))
        data.add_field('uploadId', str(upload_id))
        data.add_field('file', chunk, filename=f'chunk_{part_number}')
    
        headers = await self._prepare_headers(files=True)
    
        try:
            async with session.post(upload_chunk_url, data=data, headers=headers) as response:
                response_data = await response.json()
                if not response_data.get('success'):
                    raise ChunkUploadError(response_data.get('message'))
                else:
                    logger.info(f"Chunk #{part_number} has been successfully uploaded..")
                    self.manager_queue.put({
                        "type": "chunk_uploaded",
                        "from": "file_upload_manager",
                        "time": time.time(),
                        "path": file_path,
                        "chunk": part_number})
                    return True, part_number
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"Chunk #{part_number} uploading error: {e}")
            return False, part_number

    def count_chunks(self, file):
        total_chunks = 0
        initial_position = file.tell()
        file.seek(0, 0)
        while True:
            chunk = file.read(config.chunk_size)
            if not chunk:
                break
            total_chunks += 1

        file.seek(initial_position, 0)
        return total_chunks

    async def _prepare_headers(self, files=False):
        """ Prepare headers for HTTP-request. """
        headers = {
            "accept": "*/*",
            "Authorization": f"Bearer {self.auth_manager.token}"
        }
        if not files:
            headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
        return headers


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from session_manager import SessionManager
    from authentication_manager import AuthenticationManager
    
    auth_manager = AuthenticationManager()
    session_manager = SessionManager(auth_manager)

    file_upload_manager = FileUploadManager(session_manager, auth_manager)

    path = '/home/ivan/news.js'
    upload_id = 12345
    
    async def main():
        await file_upload_manager.upload_file(path, upload_id)
        await session_manager.close_session()

    asyncio.run(main())
```